# Dynamically create an arrow with a gradient

Tags: css

How could one go about dynamically generating a shape like this in CSS3:

[image]

Ignore the borders, as the important aspects are:

```
- The gradient in the arrow body, and that the gradient lasts from the tip to the end of the arrow.
- The length of the square part will vary.
```

I tried the regular `:after` method of adding a triangle to the end of a `div` element, but I couldn’t get the gradient to span both the tip and the body properly.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rtuY9/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NSS95/1/)

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 100%);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 100%);
}

div:after {
    z-index: -1;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -125px;
    top: -51px;
    margin: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #c00;

    -webkit-transform:rotate( -45deg );
       -moz-transform:rotate( -45deg );
            transform:rotate( -45deg );

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 100%);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 100%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its not exactly what I was after, but it is a good compromise. Thanks.